# If $A$ is an $R$-module with some sort of ring structure, is it true that any $R$-submodule of $A$ is an ideal of $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $A$ is an $R$-module with some sort of ring structure, is it true that any $R$-submodule of $A$ is an ideal of $A$?

Comment: Are you asking if every submodule of $A$ is a ring ideal of $A$?

Comment: If you think of the ring $R$ as an $R$-module, with scalar multiplication being the usual multiplication in $R$, then in that case yes, all the submodules are precisely the ideals of $R$.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero, the question appears to be a bit broader, but the language is too hard for me to understand.

Comment: It seems nice brotherhood in these two different species- Module and Rings. Again thanks

Comment: In fact, all ideals of $A$ should have the same rank as $A$, when this statement makes sense, and certainly all submodules don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, think of the polynomial rings. For instance, set $A=R[x]$ (which is indeed an $R$-module) and consider the $R$-submodule $M$ of all polynomials $f(x)$ such that $\deg f\le n$. This is not an ideal of $A$, since $1\in M$ but $M\ne A$.

Comment: Hey Karl, I am new learner of abstract algebra. 
So will you explain me little bit more. I know the definitions of integral domain and ring of polynomials.

Comment: @PittHarmanN-FreshmaN I made it simpler. Now, if you have something you would like me to explain better, feel free to ask.

Comment: wow you are so nice guys. Thank you all of you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of this in a simpler case, say when $R$ is a field. Then you would be asking "are all subspaces of $A$ ideals of $A$?

At this point, you might come up with the idea to look at $M_n(F)$, $n>1$. It has no nontrivial ideals, but lots of nontrivial $F$ submodules.